# How can I add "New Folder" button on TInputDirWizardPage

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have the code below and I need to give an option for the user create a new folder inside the one the user picked.

This option is not related with folder where the program is actually installed.

For example:
If the user have chosen a `D:\`, I want to give option for the user create a new folder like `D:\code\` without leaving the installation itself.

```pascal
var
  CodePage: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure ChoseCodeFolder();                   
begin
  CodePage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir,
    'Select your Code Folder', 'Where should your code folder be located?',
    'Select the folder in which your projects be located, then click Next.',
    false, '');
  CodePage.Add('');
end;
```

I read the documentation several times and i cant understand how I can do that.

I hope the question is described clearly :)

Like this image:

[image: new folder button]

Comment: The image shows dialog that you already get with the "Browse" button. So do you actually want to add button on the "browse" dialog?

Comment: Yes, this option would be ideal :)

Comment: The image i show is not what i got. Is what i wish i have. I pick the image from the internet to better explain...

Comment: See my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a value (e.g. `'Code'`) to the `ANewFolderName` parameter:

```pascal
CodePage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectDir,
  'Select your Code Folder', 'Where should your code folder be located?',
  'Select the folder in which your projects be located, then click Next.',
  false, 'Code');
```

See the documentation for [`CreateInputDirPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputdirpage):

> If AAppendDir is False and ANewFolderName is not empty, a Make New Folder button will be shown that creates a new folder with the specified default name.

[image: Browser For Folder dialog]